# React Native date and time pickers for Android doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to use this module https://github.com/nucleartux/react-native-date
But after I do step 4 "Register React Package" build failed.

> What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What did the compiler error output say?

Comment: Can you show your Java code? Remember to both import the package and call the "addPackage" method below.

Comment: Java code http://pastebin.com/PPTQxyxn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the react-native-date README, in line 17 `MainActivity` should extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`